# EXCEL VBA copy data from a week into a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sheets in a workbook, one has all the data ("hdagarb") and the other is "summary". In the data sheet, column 2 has names and column 5 has dates. These are the columns I'm concerned with. I want to get all the rows which fall within say week ending 9th of June, and copy the name in column 2 and the date in column 5 and paste it into my summary sheet. At the moment I can't even get it to copy and paste the column 2 names. Here is my code:

```
Sub finddata()


Dim todaysdate As Date
Dim thisweek As Date
Dim lastweek As Date
Dim finalrow As Long
Dim Rdate As Date
Dim i As Long

Sheets("Summary").Range("H5:H1000").ClearContents

todaysdate = Date
thisweek = (7 - Weekday(todaysdate, vbSaturday)) + todaysdate
lastweek = (7 - Weekday(todaysdate, vbSaturday)) + todaysdate - 7


finalrow = Sheets("HDAGarb").Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row


For i = 2 To finalrow

Rdate = Sheets("hdagarb").Cells(i, 5)

If Rdate > lastweek Then
    Sheets("hdagarb").Cells(i, 2).Copy
    Sheets("Summary").Range("H100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
    End If

Next i


Worksheets("summary").Activate
Worksheets("summary").Range("H5").Select

End Sub
```

The source data in column 5 is like this

```
02-Jun-2017  
-  
-  
-  
-  
12-Apr-2017  
01-May-2017
```

I want the script to ignore the entries without dates ("-").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will only perform the copy if there is a valid date in column E:

```
Sub finddata()
    Dim todaysdate As Date
    Dim thisweek As Date
    Dim lastweek As Date
    Dim finalrow As Long
    Dim newRow As Long
    Dim Rdate As Date
    Dim i As Long
    Dim srcSheet As Worksheet
    Dim dstSheet As Worksheet

    todaysdate = Date
    thisweek = (7 - Weekday(todaysdate, vbSaturday)) + todaysdate
    lastweek = (7 - Weekday(todaysdate, vbSaturday)) + todaysdate - 7

    Set srcSheet = Worksheets("HDAGarb")
    Set dstSheet = Worksheets("Summary")

    finalrow = srcSheet.Range("A" & srcSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    dstSheet.Range("H5:H" & dstSheet.Cells(dstSheet.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents
    newRow = 4

    For i = 2 To finalrow
        If IsDate(srcSheet.Cells(i, "E").Value) Then
            Rdate = CDate(srcSheet.Cells(i, 5).Value)

            If Rdate > lastweek Then 'or If Rdate > lastweek And Rdate <= thisweek Then  '???
                newRow = newRow + 1
                srcSheet.Cells(i, "B").Copy
                dstSheet.Cells(newRow, "H").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
                'Not sure whether you wanted the next two lines
                srcSheet.Cells(i, "E").Copy
                dstSheet.Cells(newRow, "I").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    dstSheet.Activate
    dstSheet.Range("H5").Select
End Sub
```

I also changed it to keep track of the row being written to in the Summary sheet so that, if one of the names in the HDAGarb sheet was blank, it would still copy it and the associated date.  (It's also faster if you don't have to keep recalculating which is the last row.)

Comment: Wow, thank you! Reading the code this is exactly what I want.